# Finding the closest function to another in a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let *H* be the Hilbert space *L$^2$*([0,1)], and let $S$ be the subspace of functions *f* $\in$ *H* satisfying $\int^1_0(1+x)f(x)dx=0$.
>
> Find the element of $S$ closest to the function $g\in H$ defined by $g(x)=1$. Prove that it is the closest element.

I think what I need to do is find the orthogonal projection of $g$ onto $S$. I'm not exactly sure how I would go about doing that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$S=(1+x)^\perp$$
Thus $S$ is closed and so we know, by the projection theorem, that there's a unique $f\in S$ such that $||f-g||=\min_{h\in S}\{||h-g||\}$.  Furthermore, this $f$ is the unique element of $S$ satisfying $(f-g)\perp S$.  But 
$$S^\perp = ((1+x)^\perp)^\perp=\overline{(1+x)}=1+x$$
so we can solve for $f$.

Comment: Great answer, although (minor objection) it seems confusing to me to not distinguish between $1+x$ and the subspace generated by $1+x$. You're also not distinguishing between the function $x \mapsto 1+x$ and the expression $1+x$, but I think that's more common and excusable.